# alfresco evaluator on custom component

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I've made a component and I'd like to show that component on the document-details page only if the document has a certain aspect, so I tried to use an evaluator. I've added this bean in `custom-slingshot-application-context.xml`

```
<bean id="evaluator.doclib.metadata.hasInvoiceAspect"
      parent="evaluator.doclib.action.propertyNotNull">
   <property name="property" value="inv:invoice"/>
</bean>
```

In `document-details.xml` I added this

```
<component>
   <region-id>custom-comp</region-id>
   <sub-components>
      <sub-component id="default">
         <evaluations>
            <evaluation>
               <evaluators>
                  <evaluator type="evaluator.doclib.metadata.hasInvoiceAspect"/>
               </evaluators>
               <url>/components/custom/custom-comp</url>
            </evaluation>
        </evaluations>
     </sub-component>
  </sub-components>
</component>
```

I guess I've missed something as the component doesn't show up. I have 2 files named custom-slingshot, I tried both `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension` and `tomcat/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/web-extension`.

Am I completely wrong with this? Is it possible to achieve what I want like that? How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

There is a predefined evaluator to check whether a node has an aspect called **evaluator.doclib.action.hasAspect**. You simply need to create a bean with this evaluator as the parent and give an aspect to check against in the properties:

*added to some -context.xml in web-extension

```
<bean id="my.custom.evaluator" parent="evaluator.doclib.action.hasAspect">
    <property name="aspects">
        <list>
            <value>my:hasInvoiceAspect</value>
        </list>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

Then you'll reference that bean in your DocLibActions config added to *extension-modules.xml (web-extension/site-data/extensions)...

```
<config condition="DocLibActions" evaluator="string-compare">
    <actions>
        <action...>         
            <!-- Custom evaluator -->
            <evaluator>my.custom.evaluator</evaluator>
       </action>
    </actions>
</config>
```

Voila.

More info on [predefined evaluators](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/doclib-predefined-evaluators-reference.html).
Good sample project [here](https://github.com/gravitonian/all-in-one-spock-testing/tree/master/add-action-doclib-share).